# HOW do I install AWS addon for Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've downloaded and can run Visual Studio for Mac but the whole reason why I did this was to use the AWS addon to run on Visual Studio so that I can create pre-signed URLs for a couple of files in my S3 bucket.

The file I downloaded is an .msi file.  Which means I need a Windows machine.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to create pre-signed URLs, I would recommend using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). It is available for Windows, Mac and Linux.

The [`aws s3 presign`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/presign.html) command can generate pre-signed URLs.

It's also very simple to code yourself, eg:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

S3 = S3Connection(
    aws_access_key_id = 'AKIAABCDEFG', # Stack
    aws_secret_access_key = 'abcdefg'
)

print S3.generate_url(
    expires_in = 6000, # seconds
    method     = 'GET',
    bucket     = 'foo-bucket',
    key        = 'bar.jpg',
    query_auth = True, # Sign the request
    force_http = True  # Not HTTPS
)
```

Comment: After installing Xcode, Python, pip, and then AWS CLI, I think I can now follow what you've suggested.  However, if I use/modify your sample code above, am I doing this in the Terminal at my .aws.user prompt$ ?

Comment: You can use the `aws s3 presign` command in the AWS CLI (which is very simple -- see [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/presign.html)). Alternatively, you could run a python program like shown above. They are separate options.

Comment: I saw the documentation link for AWS CLI but I must be getting something wrong.  If I want a bucket to expire after 20 mins, wouldn't I type `aws s3 presign s3://specialbucket --expires-in 1200` ?

Comment: You need to identify the specific object (file) to which the URL links, eg: `aws s3 presign s3://specialbucket/foo.txt --expires-in 1200`.